# Howto create a new cell in tabular when using \collectcell

Tags: tables, collcell

I have to display a table with 6 columns, the last 2 cells of each row are
calculated from the first 4. In the MWE this calculation is simulated by
just displaying these values connected with a hyphen, but it is more
complicated in reality.

I have 2 working solutions:

In the first one, the user (of the package where the table is defined) must
enter 2 empty cells, e.g.

```
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & & \\
```

In the second solution I use a separate table with 2 columns where the
calculated values are displayed. Here the user can specify

```
1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
```

Although the second one is a bit user friendlier, it creates an aligning
problem if I want to "suspend the table temporarily" and put some text in
between.

It is possible to create the 2 last cells of a row on the fly, but I don't
manage to get it work when I do the calculations with \collectcell from the
package collcell.

Does any one knows a solution for this?

The MWE yields: Misplaced alignment tab character &.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{collcell,xparse}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\collectcell\testcol}c<{\endcollectcell}}

\newcounter{Cnt}
\setcounter{Cnt}{0}

\ExplSyntaxOn
 \newcommand{\testcol}[1]{%
  \stepcounter{Cnt}
  \str_case_x:nn {\theCnt}
   {
    {1}{#1 \gdef\One{#1}}
    {2}{#1 \gdef\Two{#1}}
    {3}{#1 \gdef\Three{#1}}
    {4}{
         #1 \setcounter{Cnt}{0}
        & \One-\Two & \Three-#1
         \tabularnewline
       }
   }
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\begin{tabular}{CCCC|cc}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4
 5 & 6 & 7 & 8
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You cannot add more cells when processing a cell.  Have a look at one of the many spreadsheet packages, e.g. [`spreadtab`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spreadtab).

Comment: Thank you Henri, I hesitate to use spreadtab (or any other spreadsheet package) and for the time being I'll use my 2nd solution.